# Android: Displaying a list of images fetched from urls

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

Hello Android developers,

I want to create a ListFragment of images that are fetched from about 20 urls, so roughly 20 images.

1. What's the best way to do this? Save them as a List, or write them to disk and then show them in a grid/list?
2. Either way, how do I write them to the drawable location?

Answer (score 0):

1. It's up to you, GridView and ListView are different in the UI.

2.
Don't invite the wheel, use [Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), Or watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo) google's video. It rocks!

Good luck